# Selenium stops while running

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Đây là code:

```
    if (C < 1):
        driver.get(U)
        time.sleep(5)
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="movie_player"]/div[5]/button').click()
        time.sleep(10)
        C + 1
        while (C > V):
            driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
            time.sleep(10)
            C + 1
            print (C)
```

When running it will crash and exit.
But, when the code exits, vs does not leave a message
error .

Hope everybody help please.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What do you think `C + 1` line should do?

Comment: I use C to count the number of iterations then give V(V is the spinBox variable in PyQt5)
compare in while (C > V):
to specify the number of repetitions of the command after pressing pushButton

Comment: `C + 1` do nothing. You need either `C = C + 1` or `C += 1` to increment counter

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two different issues with your code.

1. `C + 1` isn't changing `C` at all. Maybe you mean `C += 1`, which will actually increment it if that's what you want.
2. You have an infinite loop if your code gets inside there. `C` will always be greater than `V` once inside, unless you decrement `C` or increment `V`.

Comment: V is the spinBox
in PyQt5.
I use it to specify commands